# Coffeescript classes and scope and fat and thin arrows

Tags: coffeescript, scope, arrow-functions

In a fat arrowed function of a coffeescript class, how can I access the scope of the class as well as the function?

Example:

```
class Example
  foo: ->
    $('.element').each =>  # or ->
      @bar($(this))        # I want to access 'bar' as well as the jquery element
  bar: (element) ->
    element.hide()
```

So in this example, if I use a => then the @ refers to the this of the class but the 'this' is then wrong, whereas if I use a -> for the each, then the 'this' is correctly scoped but but then how do I reference the class function bar?

Thanks!

Comment: I've found a temporary solution: Using a -> and then referencing bar using Example::bar. It works but it's ugly. Anyone have any prettier solutions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because in CoffeeScript `@` is an alias for `this` i.e. when you compile your .coffee to .js `@` will be replaced with `this`.

If `Example::bar` is ugly, I don't think there are 'prettier' solutions.

You can store a reference to `this` before calling `.each`:

```
class Example
  foo: ->
    self = @
    $('.element').each ->
      self.bar($(this)) # or self.bar($(@))
  bar: (element) ->
    element.hide()
```

Comment: Thanks mak. Good answer. It's shown I've not missed something obvious and also I like the self = @ option. I should have thought of that. Still getting used to it, but liking it.

Comment: On a separate note (of style), what do you think of the syntax ($ '.foo') instead of $('.foo') ? Topfunky was trying to push the first style but I'm undecided...

Answer (score 16):

While mak is right, he fails to point out that in coffee script you rarely need jQuery's `each` method, which as you noticed, punches your execution context in the face without your permission.

```
class Example
  foo: ->
    for element in $('.element')
      @bar $(element)

  bar: (element) ->
    element.hide()
```

Coffee script's looping features support the concept of `each` without any actual custom library code at all.  And they also do not generate a new scope or context meaning you dont need a fat arrow of any kind.

Comment: Good stuff Squeegy! You're totally right. I've left mak's answer as the accepted one but your way is a lot neater - and the way to go. I'd launched into coffeescript with a conversion of some old js which is why I'd hit this problem but now I know better. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

After checking different solution. Here something appear for me as the most complete sample  with each and click :

```
class MainApp
  self = []

  constructor: ->
    self = @

  toDoOnClick: (event) ->
    self.bar($(event.target)) #hide the clicked object

  bar: (element) ->
    element.hide()

  sampleMethod:->
    $(".myDiv").click (e) -> self.toDoOnClick(e)
    $('.element').each ->
      self.bar($(this))
```