# Access class properties and methods from onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

i'm new on coffeescipt, and i wanted to create classes, but there is a problem, when i create a "click" action on a buttons, how can i access class properties? and other class functions??

## Edit question with better class example

Thanks for these two replies, the thing is:
i have one only file, there will not be so much javascript for now, so, i wanted to create a class, and have separated "objects" by sections, let me put a better example:

```
class SiteName
  isMenuActive: false
  cartItems: {}

  constructor: ->
    that = @
    $('.openMenu').on 'click', ->
     that.menu.open()

  menu:
    open: () ->
      # How can i access "isMenuActive" Here??
      # using @ or this, is referer to the item itself, because this action is called with "onclick"
      if isMenuActive 
        alert 'menu is active'

    close: () -> console.log 'close menu'
    other_action: () -> console.log 'blah'
    call_cart_actions: () ->
      # how can i call cart properties/functions from "cart" in this same namespace??

  cart:
    add: () -> 
      # how to access SiteName.cartItems ¿?
      # How to call other class function??
    remove: () ->
```

The problem i reallyhave, is that i like to put all my "triggers" (click, hover...) in constructor, but, once i call these functions, how can i referer to "SiteName" properties or other objects/functions of that class/namespace??

its a good practice to have the code like this?? having "menu" and "cart" on same "site" class, or its better to keep them on files/classes separated??

thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you need the extra `func` namespace in there? What do you mean by "`actions` is private"?

Comment: Thanks for you two, i've improved my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some research I did, specifically this SO question helped:

[Coffeescript classes and scope and fat and thin arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941442/coffeescript-classes-and-scope-and-fat-and-thin-arrows)

it looks like you need to store the `this` reference as part of the constructor. Here's a hacked version of your code that I put together to demonstrate:

```
class actions
  isActive: false
  self = {}

  constructor: ->
      self = @

  func:
    click: () ->
      alert self.isActive
    close: () ->
      console.log "close function"

f = new actions
f.func.click()
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, this is a good solution, until i find a better way or is therese another solutions i'll use yours.

Comment: Yeah, there might be a CoffeeScript way of doing this, but I was unable to find any docs that pointed this out.